# Is there an online Esperanto word stem "diagrammer?"

Tags: translation, dictionaries

Is there a site or resource that will take an Esperanto word and diagram the different components? For example, given "malsanulejo," the "diagrammer" would return something like:

mal-: prefix meaning "opposite"
san-: root meaning "healthy"
-ul-: suffix meaning "human"
-ej-: suffix meaning "place"
-o: word ending for a noun

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a tool that does morphological analysis for Esperanto. There is a great variety of such tools around and I remember that some of them were also trained and tested for Esperanto.

A quick search for "Esperanto morphological tool" brought up a reference to [Theresa Guinnard's Esperanto Word Segmenter](https://github.com/tguinard/EsperantoWordSegmenter) on GitHub, I am sure there are more tools outside.

Answer (score 4):

I often use [Simpla Vortaro](http://www.simplavortaro.org/ser%C4%89o?s=malsanulejo). It is primarily a dictionary, with the same database as [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/), but with a "Vortfarada Serĉo" section which decomposes the entry. If more than one decomposition is possible, they are all listed and the most likely one comes first (for instance with [kolego](http://www.simplavortaro.org/ser%C4%89o?s=kolego)).